# Difference between type and object primitive objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

From what I understand of Python 3, the type `type` is the meta-class that is used to create Class objects, so `type` is to `object` as "Car" is to "Jaguar", through a process of calling its `__call__` method which then calls the class's `__new__` and `__init__` methods, returning the instance of the class itself.

At the normal level, the relation between type and object makes perfect sense; everything is an object (subclasses `object`), and everything has a type; the type of the object `5` is `int`, and `int`'s type is `type` itself. Hence `isinstance(5, int)` and `isinstance(int, type)` are true. However, `isinstance(5, type)` is not true since `5` is not a class object, it's an instance of a class.

This article: http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html#object-type-example

Hence defines an object as having exactly one type. But at the very primitive level, of the classes `type` and `object` themselves, the relationship between them confuses me. `type` is a subclass of `object`, as seen in its `__bases__`, but `object` itself is an instance of `type`.

If describing something like 5 can be split into "meat" and "bones", where "meat" represents the actual creation of it in memory and assigning values to it, and "bones" the definition of how it should be, of its legal range of values and behaviours, does this mean that, at the very core, `type` is responsible for creating the "meat" of class objects, and `object` is responsible for defining the "bones"? If so, what is the "meat" equivalent of creating an instance of a class, if the "bones", in this case, is the class `int`?

Comment: `object` is really just the common set of properties all objects in Python support, so I would call object the "bare bones" of an instance/class/metaclass. A class (like `int`) is really just an extension of type one level down. `type` dictates what you can and cannot do with a class while the class dictates what you can and cannot do with an instance.

Comment: Right, but is it possible to put in attributes in meta-classes which affect instances of the class they created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every class of objects in Python inherits the behaviours of the `object` class. Firstly, it means that

```
>>> isinstance(x, object)
True
```

will be true in Python 3 no matter what `x` happens to be bound to. It also means that everything will also inherit the methods of the `object` as such, unless overridden by a more specific class. Thus, `x == y` will resort to `object.__eq__` if neither of `x` or `y` overrode the `__eq__` method.

`type` in Python 3 is also an object - it inherits from object:

```
>>> isinstance(type, object)
True
```

It means that `type` is an object, and it has inherited the behaviour from the `object` class. That is what enables one to write things like

```
>>> type == type
True
>>> type.__eq__
<slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'object' objects>
```

The `type.__eq__` was inherited from the `object` class.

But the `object` class itself is also a type:

```
>>> isinstance(object, type)
True
```

It means that the class `object` as an object inherits the behaviour of `type` - `type` is object's metaclass.

And of course `type`'s metaclass is type:

```
>>> isinstance(type, type)
True
```

And the class `object` is an `object` too:

```
>>> isinstance(object, object)
True
```

When you construct an instance of class, the class itself is responsible for both the meat and bones for that class, but perhaps one could put the distinction in that the bones follows the ordinary class inheritance, and meat is split between the class and the metaclass lineage; and the metaclass is also the bones for the class object itself.

Comment: In drawing that distinction does it mean that despite any meta class lineage (by default, builtin, or custom meta-classes) only defining the instantiation of the class object itself, they still act to outline the template of each instance? May I clarify if meta classes can define methods to which their respective class objects and class instances may call upon?

Comment: meta classes can define methods that the class objects can call; and they can extend the class object itself with methods that the instances have, but not directly. Because an instance of a class is not an instance of the *metaclass*.

Comment: i.e. "Mercato" is a "Human" and a "Human" is a "Species" does not mean that "Mercato" is a "Species".

Comment: "and they can extend the class object itself with methods that the instances have, but not directly" could you clarify on that? Can the instances call on such methods?

Comment: the question here is not "can they be called or not" but whether they readily show on the instances.

Comment: Everything can call everything in Python. My point is that if a method `bar` is called on the `Foo` class: `Foo.bar()`, if the metaclass of `Foo` has the method `bar`. However, an instance of `Foo`, say `baz = Foo()`, will not have that method `bar` unless the metaclass injects that method into the class namespace of `Foo`.