# Why 'issubclass(object, type)' gives false (in python)?

Tags: python, class, object, hierarchy, class-hierarchy

I'm confused in python class hierarchy.

I want to know the relation between type and object.

object is the top of 'issubclass()' function.
type is the top of 'thing.**class**' and 'type(thing)'. (I intentionally didn't use the word object again to avoid confusion. instead I used thing.)

Surprisingly isinstance(object, type) and isinstance(type, object) both return true.

Explain the hierarchy in detail. Thanks

I mean which one was written first? type? or object?

Comment: what do you mean by "is top of"?  Perhaps provide some sample code to work with

Comment: top of means anything that I put in for example issubclass(), then I put the result in issubclass() again until I reach what would recursively appear. in this case it would be object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between type and object primitive objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42456590/difference-between-type-and-object-primitive-objects)

Comment: no, but it's very much related. thanks.

Comment: Often type systems have some sort of nonsensical or recursive root. Since you can obviously treat `type` like any object (pass it around, it has attributes etc.), it must be an instance of *something*…

Answer (score 1):

In Python, everything is an object, so:

```
isinstance(type, object) == True
```

Since `object` is a type constructor, it's a subclass of `type`:

```
isinstance(object, type) == True
```